# Object.hasOwn(<p>.style, 'display') returns false, why?

Tags: javascript

I had the strange thought of checking to make sure a paragraph element's style had the display property with `Object.hasOwn(pitem.style, 'display')` but trying it produced an error.

Anyone know why?

I don't think MDN documentation really says this see the below references

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration

Here's a full working example using html opened with my browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function paragraphDisplayStyle() {
        let pitem = document.getElementById('pitem');
        //console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(pitem));
        console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(pitem.style)); // CSS2PropertiesPrototype
        console.log(pitem.style.display); // empty string
        console.log(Object.hasOwn(pitem.style, 'display')); // false. but why?
        pitem.style.display = 'none'; // setting the display value works fine
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="pitem" onclick="paragraphDisplayStyle()">Content</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Oh wow it's browser specific. In Chrome this works fine

```
console.log(Object.hasOwn(pitem.style, 'display')) //returns true
```

In Firefox it does not (v116.0.1 64bit).

For shame! This should work though right? Firefox is slacking? Is that my answer?

In my situation it doesn't really hurt to assume it's there since setting the value has always worked.

Comment: You can see the difference when running your code, in Firefox the style properties are in the prototype, in Chromium they're own properties.

Comment: Ohh. Much appreciated. What if I actually don't care if the property is 'its own' or not? Is there something I can do? I'm obviously using the wrong method I just realized.

Comment: Ah okay. Had no idea the `in` operator was a thing in js! Now I know :)

Comment: Why are you checking whether the property exists?

Answer (score 0):

In my situation the the `in` operator is the right way to go. The js own vs inherited distinction means nothing to my use case. I just wanted to check if the property was there (and assure myself it would not cause an error to access it). I guess my original question was to know why the hasOwn() method returned false but now I'm less interested in Firefox implementation details than I am moving forward with my intended check.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in